# Clearpage without pagebreak?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

Is there a command which does the same like `\clearpage` (typesetting all floats which have not been typeset yet) **but** then does *not* insert a pagebreak but continues with the following text/graphics on the same page?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes, and this is discussed as one of the advantages of the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage). Use

```
\afterpage{\clearpage}
```

This will flush all processed floats after the current page has been completely set, technically avoiding a visible `\clearpage`. See the first use-case in the [`afterpage` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/afterpage.pdf) (page 1):

> Sometimes LaTeX's float positioning mechanism gets overloaded, and all
>   floating figures and tables drift to the end of the document. One may
>   flush out all the unprocessed floats by issuing a `\clearpage`
>   command, but this has the effect of making the current page end
>   prematurely. Now you can issue `\afterpage{\clearpage}` and the
>   current page will be filled up with text as usual, but then a
>   `\clearpage` command will flush out all the floats before the next
>   text page begins.

Comment: But \afterpage still issues a \clearpage. At least that's the case for me, and that's also how i understand the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work as desired. @philipp described it below: if a new section starts in the middle of the page, the floats from that new section will still appear above the section title. The solution with `\FloatBarrier` solution did work as desired.

Answer (score 112):

I believe you may be after the `\FloatBarrier` command from the `placeins` package. It forces Tex to typeset all remaining floats at that point and doesn't include a `\clearpage` afterwards.

Comment: Both ways are not equivalent. This one has the "advantage", that if a new section starts in the middle of the page, floats of this section do not appear above the section's headline.

Comment: Just want to add: you may need to install `texlive-latex-extra` to use `placeins` package since it is not part of the standard `texlive-latex-recommended`.

Comment: Note that the definition of `\FloatBarrier` in `kpsewhich placeins.sty` can in fact issue a `\clearpage` but only if "Some floats are stuck,"; else it seems to issue a `\newpage`.

Answer (score 5):

I made a MWE to compare different solutions.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=40mm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
%\clearpage % (variant 1)
%\afterpage{\clearpage} % (variant 2)
%\FloatBarrier % (variant 3)
%\afterpage{\FloatBarrier} % (variant 4)

\lipsum[3]

\section{bar}

\lipsum[5-7]

\end{document}
```

#### Result

##### Variant 0: nothing

[image]

- Image B is moved to the end.

##### Variant 1: `\clearpage`

[image]

- Image B is placed before anything after `\clearpage`.

##### Variant 2 `\afterpage{\clearpage}`

(see [answer by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88658/123129))

[image]

- Image B is placed after the current page ends.

#### Variant 3: `\FloatBarrier`

(see [answer by Max](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88659/123129))

[image]

Note, in this specific example variant 3 behaves as variant 1, but that's not the case in general (see example below).

##### Variant 4: `\afterpage{\FloatBarrier}`

(see [answer by stefanct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587026/123129))

[image]

Note, in this specific example variant 4 behaves as variant 2, but that's not the case in general (see example below).

### Difference between `\clearpage` and `\FloatBarrier`

Another example without Fig. B.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=40mm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\clearpage % (variant 1)
%\FloatBarrier % (variant 3)

\section{bar}
\lipsum[5-7]
\end{document}
```

#### Result

##### Variant 1: `\clearpage`

[image]

##### Variant 3: `\FloatBarrier`

[image]

- `\FloatBarrier` does not insert a page break if there are no floats to insert.

Answer (score 3):

I had success by combining the two previous answers, i.e., `\afterpage{\FloatBarrier}` (to be used directly after the float, maybe even within) in a case where a page-size table was pushed at the very end of an `acmart` document. This was inspired by a completely different [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463723/prevent-placing-figures-below-each-other). Naturally this requires both packages (`placeins` and `afterpage`). The alternatives have not - for some reason - not produced nice/acceptable results.