# Limit number of floats on a float page

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I'm creating a document with 10 figures, which I specify to sit on float pages using `\begin{figure}[p]` . All the figures are the same size and each float page can fit 6 of them.

However, I would like two float pages, each with 5 figures on, not a page of 6 then 4.

E.g. the following code produces a single float page with 4 floats, how could I generate two pages with two each?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p] \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p] \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p] \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p] \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply add `\clearpage` after the second figure.

Comment: why use floats at all in this situation and not simply use `\includegraphics` directly?

Comment: You could increase the height of one or more floats so only 5 will fit. Just stick a `\vspace{<somelength>}` before and/or after the graphic.

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered the `FloatBarrier` command from the `placeins` package, which is designed to resolve this exact problem; similarly to Max's answer on [Clearpage without pagebreak?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88657/clearpage-without-pagebreak).