# How to force a text to appear after a table

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, page-breaking

I have to show a set of four tables: one after another. Each table has almost middle page of information, and I really need them to appear before the next block of text. An example of LaTeX code is shown below:

```
text text text text...

\begin{table}
    \caption{table 1}
...............
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \caption{table 2}
...............
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \caption{table 3}
...............
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \caption{table 4}
...............
\end{table}

next text next text next text
```

As these tables cannot fit in one page, LaTeX need two or three pages to show all of them. But, here is my problem: since there are empty spaces between one table and another (because of the end of the pages), LaTeX put the subsequent text in these spaces, showing the rest of the tables after it.

In other words, I want LaTeX to behave exactly as the code says: first show all the tables (no matter how much empty space may exist between them), and only show the rest of the text after the last table.

Comment: Use tabular rather than table if you don't want them to float.

Comment: But I also need the caption, and, as far I know, tabular don't support caption. =/

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88657/clearpage-without-pagebreak/88658#88658 help? (The second answer, not the first.)

Comment: I would use `\FloatBarrier` from the [`placeins`](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/placeins/placeins-doc.pdf) package. Nice and easy `:)`

Comment: Yeap! \FloatBarrier did the work! =D Thanks cfr and KevinC. =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ultimately, `\FloatBarrier` with `\usepackage{placeins}` package worked.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering: You put `\FloatBarrier` after the table/listing that you don't want moved.

Answer (score 11):

Typesetting several floats consecutively without allowing non-float material to be inserted as well, irrespective of bad spacing that may result, can be accomplished by loading the `float` package and using the `[H]` location specifier for the floats -- e.g., `\begin{table}[H]` -- in question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `tabular`'s and  obtaining captions for them via `caption` package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption. If it is too absorbing, one can manually use `\clearpage` after proper tables (Without true data I cannot sugest places). The result will not be too beautiful, but separating tables from text will be achieved.

Comment: The idea of '\clearpage' seems to work in some cases. I didn't checked the caption package, but it's nice to know (it was unknown to me until now). Thanks!