# How to make the appendix appear at the end

Tags: floats, appendices

I have the appendix page given by `\appendix` syntax. However, I have some figures that are appearing after the appendix. How to make sure that everything before the appendix appears before the appendix section?

Comment: Put a `\clearpage` just before `\appendix`.

Comment: Follow the guidelines in [`\clearpage` without a page break?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657/5764) before you issues your `\appendix`.