# Is it possible to place a later Figure before an earlier one?

Tags: floats

One of the figures, e.g. Figure 3, in my document takes up a whole page so is located on the following page to where it is referenced. This leaves a large blank space on the page before and so I am trying to continue the document before the Figure 3 on the next page. However, I have another Figure, Figure 4, following on shortly after. If I try to place this on the page before the full page image, it is re labelled as Figure 3. Is there a way to keep this as Figure 4 even though it will be shown in the document before Figure 3?

Comment: Not really no. They are placed via a queue, thus first in first out. You might want to move the floats around in the source code to change the order.

Comment: Related: [Clearpage without pagebreak?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657/5764)

Comment: Wouldn't it be confusing to have Figure 4 before Figure 3? ;-)

Comment: The figures have numbers so that it's easy to find them, so having them in another order would just be confusing. If you have to do either, I would say it's better to refer to Figure 4 before you refer to Figure 3.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but can't you just switch the captions? Or must the big image be called Figure 3 at all costs? :D

Comment: _why_ are you getting "a large blank space on the page before"? the whole point of the `figure` mechanism is that latex adjusts the position of figures to avoid exactly that happening. Is there some markup you are not telling us about? Please show a sample document (as in Werner's example) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, if you manipulate the counters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,graphicx,lipsum,float}
\newsavebox{\pagefigure}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\afterpage{%
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Another figure}
    \addtocounter{figure}{2}% "A figure appears after this one"
  \end{figure}
  \vfill
  \clearpage
}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \stepcounter{figure}% "A figure appears before this one"
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{An image}
  \addtocounter{figure}{-2}% Revert to tradition figure sequence
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

The above technique requires you to know the figure order and therefore the counter sequence; something that goes against "leaving things to (La)TeX".

A better approach would be to retain the figure numbering by use `\afterpage` *without* the counter adjustments, as suggested in [Clearpage without pagebreak?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657/5764).