# My graphics are not under their own topic

Tags: graphics, pdftex, positioning, titles

My graphics are not under their own topic but elsewhere. I do  "\newpage" after the title so that each title contains its own graphics, not the graphics of another title, but it doesn't work. Latex puts my graphics on its own. Someone can help??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The answers to [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144) may be interesting/helpful for you.

Comment: In order to "flush" floating objects (such as `figure`s and `table`s), you can also use `\clearpage`; if you want to do so *without* starting a new page, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657/158639 has some tips.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text has some more practical advice regarding floats positioning.

Comment: From your question one can guess that probably you do not know what are the LaTeX floats and why they they do what they do, but we cannot see what are doing exactly, and a good answer depend on this. Please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. For the MWE use standard examples images (`example-image` or the same followed by `-a`, `-b` or `-c`) and for recreate a long text  `\usepackage{lipsum}` in the preample and some like `\lipsum[1-3]` to write 3 dummy praragrahs.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388 has practically everything you need to know about (controlling) the positions of floats.