# How to center a table wider than `\textwidth` in `pdflscape` in LaTeX?

Tags: blank-page, pdflscape

I made a table wider than `\textwidth` in `pdflscape` in LaTeX, so I put it in a new geometry with `\newgeometry`. After the table, I restored the geometry with `restoregeometry`. But there is a blank before the table. Is there a way to omit the blank before the table or another way to put the table center in `pdflscape`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularray,afterpage,geometry,pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{New section}
\lipsum{1-6}
\afterpage{\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{longtblr}{
                colspec={X[l,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,2em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,4em] X[c,3em] X[c,6em] X[c,3.2em]},colsep=1pt,rowhead=1
            }
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
    }\restoregeometry
\lipsum{7-12}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed codes to :

```
\afterpage{\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
    \begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{longtblr}{
                colspec={X[l,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,2em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,4em] X[c,3em] X[c,6em] X[c,3.2em]},colsep=1pt,rowhead=1
            }
            \newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        \end{longtblr}\restoregeometry
    \end{landscape}
    }
```

The blank was removed, but the next page after the table is abnormal.
[image]

Comment: As a quick clarification request: (1) Do you wish to remove the space on the 1st page shown on your screenshot (the portrait page)? I am struggling in understanding what extra space you are referring to. (2) You notified that you decided to place the table in `pdflscape` in order to make it wider. Are you looking for a solution that will place the table on a **portrait** page, but to make the table wider than `\textwidth`? Thank you very much!

Comment: @MiriamBriskman Thanks for your reply. (1) Yes, I hope to remove the space on the 1st page; (2) My table will contain too many contents which are not suited for `portrait` page. In this case, I replaced the contents with just numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** **Y.zeng** noted that, after the `\afterpage` command, paragraphs continue beyond the bottom margin.

To make the pages after the landscape mode return to their 'normal' display, without any paragraphs continuing beyond the bottom margin, add the macro call `\clearpage` right before the closing `}` of the `\afterpage` macro.

The decision to use `\clearpage` is based on the explanation brought in the answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88658/256551.

Here is the full, correctly-working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularray,afterpage,geometry,pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{New section}
\lipsum{1-6}
\afterpage{
    \newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
    \begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{longtblr}{
                colspec={X[l,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,2em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,4em] X[c,3em] X[c,6em] X[c,3.2em]},colsep=1pt,rowhead=1
            }
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}\restoregeometry
    \clearpage % <------ Add this macro call
    }
\lipsum{7-12}

\lipsum{7-12}
\end{document}
```

Then, the PDF pages will look like:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

---

Your 2nd version of `\afterpage`, as you specified it in your question, should remove all spaces on all the portrait pages.

The full code should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularray,afterpage,geometry,pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{New section}
\lipsum{1-6}
\afterpage{\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
    \begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{longtblr}{
                colspec={X[l,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,2em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,4em] X[c,3em] X[c,6em] X[c,3.2em]},colsep=1pt,rowhead=1
            }
            \newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        \end{longtblr}\restoregeometry
    \end{landscape}
    }
\lipsum{7-12}
\end{document}
```

and the PDF pages look as follows:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this the format you were looking to get? Thank you!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. If you change `\lipsum{7-12}` to `\lipsum{7-12}\lipsum{7-12}`, you will find the page after the table is weird at the bottom.

Comment: @Y.zeng, thank you very much for your important concern. I will look into this issue now, and will edit the answer accordingly should I find that the change works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Y.zeng, I believe a solution was found! Just add `\clearpage` before the closing brace `}` of the `\afterpage` macro. The answer was added to include this solution. Please let us know if this solution works. Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: There is an sutomatic \clearpage at the beginning and end of both landscape and \newgeometry-\restoregeometry.  After all, any floats in the queue will have a different width.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thank you very much for noting this. I based my answer on the idea at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88658/256551 (I should probably add this link to my answer.)

Comment: @MiriamBriskman Although from my knowledge I can't understand what you said totally, you hele me a lot and help me resolve the problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Y.zeng, thank you very much for your kind words!

Comment: Interestingly, `\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}` also works.

Comment: Based on page #42 of the doc on `geometry` at https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf, the `\restoregeometry` macro is defined as `\newcommand{\restoregeometry}{\clearpage\Gm@restore@pkg\Gm@changelayout}`. So it seems, as you suspected, that `\clearpage` is present at the beginning of the definition, but not at its end. Thank you very much, @JohnKormylo, for raising this idea!

Comment: @MiriamBriskman Hello, I have found another question: the next page after the table has not page number if page number was put at the bottom of pages.

Comment: @Y.zeng, thank you very much for your response. It looks like the new question you raised deserves to become an independent question. First, check if you can find any online similar questions that may help in solving yours. If you can't find anything helpful, create another question here on the website. Good luck!

Comment: @MiriamBriskman Thanks very much. Let me create a new one!

Comment: @Y.zeng, thank you. Good luck!

Comment: @MiriamBriskman Thanks! Have a good day ahead!