# How to resume the page number at the footer after the `pdflscape` in LaTeX？

Tags: header-footer

I use `pdflscape` to contain a table. After this page, the page number which should be at the bottom of that page is missing. How should I resume it? There is no page number at the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularray,afterpage,geometry,pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{New section}
\lipsum{1-6}
\afterpage{\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
    \begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{longtblr}{
                colspec={X[l,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,2em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,4em] X[c,3em] X[c,6em] X[c,3.2em]},colsep=1pt,rowhead=1
            }
          %  \newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape} \restoregeometry\clearpage
    }
\lipsum{7-12}\lipsum{7-12}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be square brackets for `\lipsum[1]`. And this is how to achieve that:

> Edit: To answer your question in the comment:

`\aftergroup` to make you `\restoregeometry` right after the current group. Because sometime macros or package commands may contain multiple groups in the definition. So you may not properly reset the geometry for after page.

The `lipsum` package [document](https://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/macros/latex/contrib/lipsum/lipsum.pdf) have the definition for  `\lipsum` marco. You can check it out (on page.3). So `\lipsum` only take 2 optional args, first one is the `par range` and second one is the `sentence range`. Latex treat stuff in `[ ]` as a optional arg. So if you do `\lipsum{1-5}`, it will treat the {1-5} as the following contents that you want to type out and use `\lipsum` default par range, which will be 1-7, to execute command `\lipsum` to output . So `\lipsum` and `\lipsum{1-20}` will basically output the same thing, except you will see `1-20` right after the dummy text. Latex don't issue errors when you do this. So sometimes you need to check documentation of package in order to properly use a command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularray,afterpage,geometry,pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{New section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\afterpage{\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{longtblr}{
                colspec={X[l,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,2em] X[c,3em] X[c,3em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,4em] X[c,3.5em] X[c,4em] X[c,3em] X[c,6em] X[c,3.2em]},colsep=1pt,rowhead=1
            }
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18\\
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}\aftergroup\restoregeometry\clearpage
    }
\lipsum[7-16]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tom, please view https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646431/how-to-center-a-table-wider-than-textwidth-in-pdflscape-in-latex/, in which the author of the question indicated that they wish to avoid having the vertical space on the 2nd page. However, the given code in your answer makes this space persist. Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: Why after you added `\aftergroup`, the page number was shown?

Comment: Before, I used `\lipsum[1-5]`, but somebody told me to use `\lipsum{1-5}`, so what's the difference between `{ [` in `lipsum`?

Comment: @MiriamBriskman His modified answer resolved the vertical space. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Y. It is too long to response you in the comment. So I add it to the answer

Comment: @Tom, your edition to the answer indeed resolves all the aforementioned issues, so my 1st comment is obsolete now. Thank you very much again!

Comment: @Miriam You are welcome. Thank you for mention it to me, cause OP didn't include that in the question. And I don't have idea which relate to another post.

Comment: Thank you, @Tom!

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your added answers. Have a nice day ahead.

Comment: @Tom  I found there is no need to add `\clearpage` here, as I deleted it, all things are right.